# Is Hillingdon just an underground station? If so, where is Google getting its information?

Tags: london, train-stations, google-search, trainline

I searched for railway stations near Uxbridge, and Google Maps gave me this:
[image]

With regular trains to Slough on GWR:
[image]

However, neither nationalrail.co.uk or Train Line recognise this as a valid journey. Further, all Google searches of Hillingdon station refer to it as a tube station. This, plus the fact every other station on the same line on Google Maps is marked with an Underground Roundel:
[image]

Whereas Hillingdon is marked with a National Rail junction icon:

[image]

Leads me to think this is surely an error in Google Maps. What I can’t fathom though, is where the information about trains to Slough would be coming from.

Bonus points for information on how to get this corrected.

Comment: On the maps at tfl.gov.uk, Hillingdon is not shown to be anything but an undrground station. And your first screenshot shows that it should be Chiltern Railways, but they don't list it as a station on their website.

Comment: @Henrik as I thought. So what’s going on with google?

Answer (score 37, accepted):

I think the information being shown on Google is correct (although could be clearer) And you are correct that Hillingdon is a tube station.

So what is happening? Currently (23rd, 24th, 30th December) engineering works are taking place which means GWR are unable to operate trains from Slough to Paddington. Rail replacement buses are operating between Slough and Hillingdon as a replacement where passengers are catch a tube train into central London. This is shown if you click on any of the services on Google maps.[image: Google maps rail replacement bus screenshot]

This information is also described on the GWR website (https://www.gwr.com/travel-updates/planned-engineering/christmas)

> Traveling to Reading from London Paddington
>
> Use Metropolitan line underground services between central London and Hillingdon
>
> Rail replacement coaches run from Hillingdon to Slough

You'll also notice if you zoom in very far on Google maps the tube station does appear again. [image: Google maps Hillingdon station] Which shows ordinary tube departures.

So what has gone wrong, it seems that Google is accidentally interpreting the data that has been given about these GWR coaches, or GWR have supplied wrong date. However, considering this is just for a temporary arrangement which only lasts 3 days - today being the last. I'm not sure it is worth a huge amount of trouble to be fixed. But you could use the report a problem button if you wish.

Comment: Wow, good detective skills.

Comment: I’m quite impressed by Google’s accuracy over the holiday period. They picked up on the changes to my bus times etc, which was very useful.

Answer (score 21):

There are no National Rail trains at this station. However, due to rail engineering work over the festive period, the main line is closed, so they are running replacement buses to a convenient location (Hillingdon tube station) so people can pick up the underground for a quicker onwards journey. This effectively means Hillingdon is temporarily being used by national rail *services* (the replacement buses), so it's marked as such on Google Maps. 
[image: Source 1]
[Source 2](https://www.gwr.com/travel-updates/planned-engineering/christmas)
[Source 3](http://www.brtimes.com/#!board?stn=ZHD&date=20181230)